# Vertically center ImageView and TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm trying to vertically center a TextView next to an ImageView, but it comes out like this (the image is zoomed in):

[image]

Notice how there is much more space below the TextView than there is at the top. How can I vertically center the TextView with the ImageView so there's an equal amount of space both above and below?

Here's my layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="8dp"
        android:layout_height="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        android:text="HELLO, WORLD."
        android:textSize="8dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use `match_parent` itstead of `fill_parent`, it's **deprecated**.

Comment: Instead of using an ImageView, you should use a **compound drawable**, which helps for performances.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="8dp"
        android:layout_height="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        android:text="HELLO, WORLD."
        android:textSize="8dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I had this idea too, but it doesn't seem to perfectly align it either. It leaves about 7px above the text, but only 2px below the text, in relation to the image.

Comment: This must be a problem with your image, because I haven't set any padding or margins... :/

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="8dp"
        android:layout_height="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="HELLO, WORLD."
        android:textSize="8dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Also potentially, padding/margin layout can be easily used to adjust more I believe.

Comment: 1. Why switch from LinearLayout to RelativeLayout? 2. It's still not perfectly centered. Photoshop shows about 7px above the text and only 2px below the text: http://i.imgur.com/aAc1WzC.png

Comment: I personally like Relative Layout when attempting to manipulate views that arent working like i'd expect.  Here is something I think might work though, add the gravity of the textview to the imageview.  I think its too small.  It has room underneath.